# How to add all values in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a assignment in which i have to make a hashmap of grocery stock with prices. Then, i have to make a method in which a grocery cart with these items in it exists and i have to find the total price.

This is a snippet of my `HashMap` for the store with items and prices:

```
HashMap<String, Double>stock= new HashMap<String, Double>(); 
stock.put("eggs",1.79);
stock.put("orange juice",2.5); 


public static double price(HashMap<String, Double>stock){

    HashMap<String, Integer>cart = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    cart.put("eggs", 2);
    cart.put("orange juice", 2);
}
```

this is my grocery cart where the int represents the quantity of each item in a cart. I am very new to HashMaps and am quite confused on how to reference the stock map into the price method and add it up correctly. the final answer for this would in theory be the price of 2 eggs and 2 orange juice boxes. and would greatly appreciate help

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: And even more important: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys above have given you code snippets but I'll go into a little more detail on whats going on based off Chris Bertasi answer since it's easiest to read since you are new to Hashmaps.

```
HashMap<String, Double>stock= new HashMap<String, Double>(); 
stock.put("eggs",1.79);
stock.put("orange juice",2.5);
```

What this snippet does is creates a Hashmap, you can think of it similar to relational database with two columns. Where the columns are Key and Value.

The first thing we attach (`"eggs"`) is the Key which we use to look up what it's attached too (`1.79`) then same thing to OJ. Resulting in Hashmap looks something like this.

```
Item (Key)    | Price (Value)
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
egg           | 1.79
orange juice | 2.5
```

So to get the price of egg, you can simply ask the Hashmap using `stock.get("egg")` and it will return the value `1.79` back.

The same logic is applied to the cart, where it's quantity amount rather than price (eg. 2 is returned rather than 1.79).

So once we've added the items to the cart we want to iterate through it and get the total cost.

To iterate though our stock we can use:

```
for (String item: cart.keySet())
```

What this does it will look through Key Set (i.e Key Column) and get a Key one at time and set it as item variable.

Using this knowledge we can go through the stock & cart to get price of each item and the amount the user has purchased.

```
double amount = cart.get(item); 
double price = stock.get(item);
```

using this information we can generate the total cost by using:

```
totalCost += amount * price;
```

Piecing this together gives us this snippet, where we iterate through each of key elements and retrieving the price and quantity via the `.get()` method

```
double totalCost = 0;
for (String item: cart.keySet()) {
    double amount = cart.get(item);
    double price = stock.get(item);
    totalCost += amount * price; 
}
return totalCost;
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the cart entries, converting to a line-item price, then sum.

You can use a stream for this:

```
double total = cart.entrySet().stream()
    .mapToDouble(entry -> entry.getValue() * stock.get(entry.getKey()))
    .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public static double price(HashMap<String, Double> stock){


    HashMap<String, Integer> cart = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    cart.put("eggs", 2);
    cart.put("orange juice", 2);
    // the cart hashmap now contains all the items in our shopping cart

    // we want to get the prices of all items in our cart, and multiple by the amount we are purchasing
    double cost = 0;
    for (String item: cart.keySet()) { // for every item we are purchasing
        double amount = cart.get(item); // how much we are purchasing
        double price = stock.get(item); // how much it costs
        cost += amount * price; // update the total price
    }
    return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are beginner, this piece of code might help. This is an elaborate/detailed  way of doing things:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Grocery {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         HashMap<String, Double>stock= new HashMap<String, Double>(); 
            stock.put("eggs",1.79);
            stock.put("orange juice",2.5); 

            HashMap<String, Integer>cart = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            cart.put("eggs", 2);
            cart.put("orange juice", 2);
            System.out.println(price(stock,cart));//prints the total cart value/price

    }
            public static double price(HashMap<String, Double>stock,HashMap<String, Integer>cart){

              Iterator<String> productItr = cart.keySet().iterator();//get each product in the cart
              double price=0;
              while(productItr.hasNext()){
                  String product =productItr.next();
                  price=price+( cart.get(product)*stock.get(product));
              }


                return price;
        }

}
```